# Buffer format for user-defined table types

Tags: sql-server, node.js, user-defined-types, node-mssql, tedious

I'm wanting to call a SQL Server stored procedure using node.js with the `mssql` + `tedious` module. One of the parameters I need to pass in is of a user-defined table type. I have a `UDT` parameter type available in this library which takes a `Buffer` for the value. However, I have no idea how to format a user-defined table type.

Is there a specification out there that explains how to serialize user-defined table type data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my confusion was a case of inconsistent terminology.

According to [Table Valued Parameter (TVP) Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304813.aspx) in MSDN, user-defined table types are the same as TVPs. TVPs are supported directly according to [the README of node-mssql](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql#table-valued-parameter-tvp).